# Why do they use pointer, void_pointer and other typedef inside allocator and vector classes of STL?

Tags: c++, stl, nested-types

Looking at the https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator

`value_type` is typedef(or alias) of `T`,

`pointer` is typedef(or alias) of `T*`,

`void_pointer` is typedef(or alias) of `void*`,

Why do we need this from the point of view of STL developers?
Isn't `T*` always a pointer?
Isn't `void*` always a pointer to void?
Give me some explanation or links, please.
I don't really understand this.

Comment: Take a look at the map or unordered_map containers, they will answer your question.

Comment: The idea is that STL containers can store their data in memory that is not accessible via regular pointers. Think NUMA, or think old x86 memory models with their near and far pointers.

Comment: There are non-STL allocators that can return things that are not normal pointers, see Thrust allocators or Boost.Interprocess allocators.

Comment: At the time when C++ was a teenager, we had systems with segmented memory with "near pointers" (within a segment) and "far pointers" (between segments). At that time, `T*` was not the only option. Note that it says *"(removed in C++20)"*, because it is no longer needed.

Comment: @BoP They are only removed from std::allocator. User-provided allocators can define them and they still function exactly as before, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits .

Comment: Thank's a lot! It explained much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::allocator` is just one possible implementation of the [*Allocator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) concept. There are more allocator types in the standard library and users can write their own type satisfying the *Allocator* concept and the allocator-aware standard library types such as `std::vector` will work with these allocators in place of `std::allocator` as well.

The *Allocator* concept requires these typedefs because it is *not* required that such an allocator implementation uses `void*` as void pointer or `value_type*` as pointer type. As you can see on the page I linked above, they only need to satisfy some concepts such as e.g. [*NullablePointer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/NullablePointer) that makes them behave similar to native raw pointers.

The idea is that you can implement allocators with so-called [*fancy pointers*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator#Fancy_pointers) that have different functionality than native raw pointers. One example for such a pointer type is [`boost::interprocess::offset_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/doc/html/interprocess/offset_ptr.html), which is a pointer-like type that points at an offset of itself instead of an absolute address. This is useful if you want to store containers in memory shared between processes. Because every process will map the shared memory pages at a different base virtual address in their respective address space, an absolute native pointer couldn't refer to the intended location in all processes at the same time.

Technically, because every user of an *Allocator* is supposed to access it through the [`std::allocator_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) interface which provides defaults for these typedefs, it is usually not required to actually declare them in the allocator type itself if you want the defaults that you listed. (Except for `value_type` which doesn't have a default and must always be declared.)

However `std::allocator_traits` has been added only in C++11 and `std::allocator` has always existed. So removing the typedefs is an incompatible change. Therefore they have only been deprecated in C++17 and removed in C++20 from `std::allocator` (except for `value_type`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thank's a lot! It explained much about.